# How to display or preview a uploaded images after submitted in PHP to permanent folder?

Tags: php, upload

How can I create a php page where I can display the images which I uploaded to a permanent folder?

(display images in a table )

this is form.php

```
<form dir="rtl" action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" ><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload">
</form>
```

this is upload_file.php

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1048576)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo " thanks";  
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                       "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);


    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "wrong";
  }




?>
```

thanks alot

Comment: it's unclear what you're asking here... are you looking for a redirect to another page that displays the uploaded images, or trying to send the URL to the uploaded images somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Basic [glob](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) example however if would recommend using [Directory Iterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) which gives you more flexibility

```
<?php

$dir = 'images';

$extensions = array("gif","png","jpg");

foreach( $extensions as $ext ) $images = ( isset( $images ) )? array_merge( $images, glob("$dir/*.$ext") ) : glob("$dir/*.$ext");

foreach( $images as $image ) echo "<img src=\"$image\" />";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not much in the way of an explanation (your question was rather vague...) no specifics of where the images are (in relation to the script being executed) or how you want them displayed on the page (table column names, etc)

look at php **dirname(_*FILE*_)**, **DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR** to find the location of your folder - in this case (when the script is in the `project` folder of your web-server within `www / htdocs` - depending on your server pacckage). this is referencing `project/images` folder for this example.

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'images';
//get contents of the folder
$foldercontents = array_diff(scandir($dir, 1), array('..', '.'));
//for each of the folder contents in the array
foreach($foldercontents as $key => $file)
{
    //get extension of the current file - name of file after last "." (the file extension)
    $file_ext = end(explode(".", $file));
    //allowed extensions
    $extensions = array("gif","png","jpg");
    //if the extension of the current file is allowed
    if(in_array($file_ext, $extensions))
    {
        //place the image on the page
        echo "<img src='images/'.$file/>";
    }
}
```

If I can help more, feel free to reply!